# Need to parse one more piece of information from XML with Python

Tags: python, xml

I am parsing the following XML string:

```
-<places>
    -<place place_id="11703">
         <gas_price update_time="2017-06-21 00:00:00" type="premium">17.51</gas_price>
</place>
```

I've been able to extract the place id and place the price in a header under premium, however I am unable to get extract the time.  Here is my code:

```
stationid=member.attrib.get('place_id')
servicestationprices.append(stationid)
regular_price=member.findtext("./gas_price[@type='regular']")
servicestationprices.append(regular_price)
premium_price=member.findtext("./gas_price[@type='premium']")
servicestationprices.append(premium_price)
diesel_price=member.findtext("./gas_price[@type='diesel']")
servicestationprices.append(diesel_price)
#regular_time=member.element("regular time",f='regular']")
#servicestationprices.append(regular_time)
#servicestationprices.append(regulartime)
```

The ones that I have marked with # are what I've tried, but those are not working.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I should note that there might be multiple times so I need to place the time in the proper column based on the type that follows the time.

Comment: what kind of error does the commented code raise?

Comment: It doesn't really return an error, it just doesn't fill in the value in the column, in this case I would want this to see that it has the element of type=premium and then it would append that time value: "2017-06-21 00:00:00" to a premium_time column

Comment: This started to work so thank you very much, its very similar to this example: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html where say I would want to extract the neighbor name with the direction of E into a column.